# FortesReport access violation when trying to print

Tags: delphi, printing, access-violation

I'm using FortesReport in Delphi 2007, I call "previewModal()" and it works fine but when I try to print it it gives me an Access Violation when trying to print. Anybody know if I can configure FortesReport to avoid this error?

[image: Access Violation when trying to print]

Comment: The error indicates that you are trying to access an object that is not created. Build your project with debug info, and try again. The error dialog should then include a "break" button, which give you access to the call stack and current execution point in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by updating the lib at https://github.com/fortesinformatica/fortesreport-ce, but still don't know what caused the problem.